# View Classes type hierarchy of .Net API

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I just started to learn c# and .Net 6 with Visual Studio. And I am wondering if there is a possibility to view the Classes type hierarchy of.Net API. For example, if I `Ctrl + left mouse click` a `List<string>` it would take me to the class definition `public class List<T> .....` However, is there a way in Visual Studio or somewhere else :

1. To see a graphical representation of the Type inheritance e.g. base
   classes and implemented interfaces?
2. Or for example, find out all the classes the implement `IEnumerable` interface

Sorry, it maybe sounds like a beginner or silly question. Hoping to get guidance from experienced developers here.

Comment: Click on the word "List" and press F1

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks. do you know how to find out which classes implements a specific interface?

Comment: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ilspy/9MXFBKFVSQ13

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has the [Object Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/viewing-the-structure-of-code?view=vs-2022). It's a powerful tool to navigate all the types you care about.

Comment: Thank you. I came across the Object Browser today actually it seems ok but it is still very difficult to navigate, for example, finding who implements an interface. If my memory serves me right;  when I used to develop Jave on eclipse, there is a graphical representation and an easier way to navigate base classes and interfaces.